# MVC not passing value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net MVC to provide the front end for database accesses.

PROBLEM: Data from my view is not arriving in my controller.

Specifically, I have a create view for my CreditCard model where the user enters the type, ccnumber, cardfirstname, cardlastname, expirationdate, cvc, and addressid. (addressid is an int generated by the database to uniqely identify an existing address, all others are strings)

```
@model FlightBooking.Models.CreditCard

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Credit Card</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CcNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CcNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CcNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardFirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardFirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardFirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardLastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardLastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpirationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpirationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpirationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cvc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cvc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cvc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- TODO: This needs to be a dropdown with address info -->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Account")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My Controller takes that information and uses it to insert the credit card information into the database.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FlightBooking.Models;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;

namespace FlightBooking.Controllers
{
    public class CreditCardController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly SqlParser Parser = new SqlParser();
        private static readonly SqlClient Client = new SqlClient(Parser);

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var creditCards = Client.GetCreditCards(CurrentUser.Email);
            return PartialView("Index", creditCards);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Type,CcNumber,CardFirstName,CardLastName,ExpirationDate,Cvc,AddressID")] CreditCard creditCard)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Client.InsertCreditCard(CurrentUser.Email, creditCard.Type, creditCard.CcNumber, creditCard.CardFirstName,
                        creditCard.CardLastName, creditCard.ExpirationDate, creditCard.Cvc, creditCard.AddressID);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var creditCard = Client.GetCreditCard(id);

            if (creditCard == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(creditCard);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditPost(string id)
        {
            if (id.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var creditCard = Client.GetCreditCard(id);
            ModelState.Remove("id");
            if (TryUpdateModel(creditCard, "", new[] { "Type", "CcNumber", "CardFirstName", "CardLastName", "ExpirationDate", "Cvc", "AddressID" }))
            {
                try
                {
                    Client.UpdateCreditCard(creditCard.Type, creditCard.CcNumber, creditCard.CardFirstName,
                        creditCard.CardLastName, creditCard.ExpirationDate, creditCard.Cvc, creditCard.AddressID);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                }
                catch (Exception /* dex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                }
            }

            return View(creditCard);
        }

        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var creditCard = Client.GetCreditCard(id);
            if (creditCard == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(creditCard);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            Client.DeleteCreditCard(CurrentUser.Email, id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
    }
}
```

Hitting Save sends me back to my account index view with no error messages. While debugging, I noticed that my ModelState doesn't end up with a key entry for AddressID and the CreditCard object that is generated has an addressID of 0. All other attributes are properly written to both the ModelState and the CreditCard object.

this.ValueProvider[5].Non-Public members._values (which is the System.Web.Mvc.JqueryFormValueProvider) show all seven attributes and an additional _RequestVerificationToken.

Can anyone explain why my AddressID isn't getting from the ValueProvider to the ModelState?

Included below is my CreditCard model in case something I've done in it is what's precluding properly passing data.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace FlightBooking.Models
{
    public class CreditCard
    {
        // TODO: input restrictions
        [DisplayName("Provider")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Number")]
        public string CcNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string CardFirstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string CardLastName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Expiration")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("CVC")]
        public string Cvc { get; set; }
        public int AddressID;
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        public CreditCard() { }

        public CreditCard(string type, string ccNumber, string cardFirstName, string cardLastName, DateTime expirationDate,
            string cvc, Address address)
        {
            Type = type;
            CcNumber = ccNumber;
            CardFirstName = cardFirstName;
            CardLastName = cardLastName;
            ExpirationDate = expirationDate;
            Cvc = cvc;
            Address = address;
        }

        public CreditCard(string type, string ccNumber, string cardFirstName, string cardLastName, DateTime expirationDate,
            string cvc, int addressID)
        {
            Type = type;
            CcNumber = ccNumber;
            CardFirstName = cardFirstName;
            CardLastName = cardLastName;
            ExpirationDate = expirationDate;
            Cvc = cvc;
            AddressID = addressID;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: All credit card information included here is randomly generated and doesn't actually represent an actual card, so I'm not worried about security at this point.

PPS: Of note, it is also having the same problem when attempting to edit an existing creditcard. It's properly populating the form with the initial values, but submitting the edit results in the same situation where the AddressID doesn't end up at my controller despite being in the ValueProvider. Edit included below for reference.

```
@model FlightBooking.Models.CreditCard

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Credit Card</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Type)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CcNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CcNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CcNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardFirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardFirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardFirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardLastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardLastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpirationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpirationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpirationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cvc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cvc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cvc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- TODO: This needs to be a dropdown -->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Account")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: From what you describe it sounds like the problem is inside `Client.InsertCreditCard()` which you haven't included here. Also be aware that's actually illegal to store CCV numbers in a database, and there are very strict regulations and policy requirements controlling how you can store and transmit any credit card data (PCI-DSS).

Comment: So your problem is that, AddressID property is not filled by model binder ? Are you sending a valid value to that from your form ?

Comment: The zero value for AddressID is being passed to Client.InsertCreditCard() which is why the database is rejecting the insert (0 is not a valid addressID). So, the problem is before I get to Client.InsertCreditCard.

Comment: I am sending an integer value. In the case of Edit, I'm sending the value that was already present. In the case of Add, I'm sending a value that I'm sure exists as an addressID in the database.

Comment: @Shyju Yes, I am inputting a non-zero value into the AddressID text box on my form. I agree that it should be properly bound... I can't for the life of my figure out why it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AddressID` proeprty should be **set**table.

```
public class CreditCard
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
}
```

When the form is posted, the default model binder will read the posted form data and map the values to the corresponding properties of your `CreditCart` class object. If your property is not settable, model binder cannot set the value to that property.

Answer (score 0):

In your Html.BeginForm helper, you need to add parameters on what controller those input you are going to pass in like so:

```
@model Models.MyModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("MyActionName","MyControllerName"))
{
    @Html.TextboxFor(m => m.ModelProperty)
    <!-- input button will send the form data to the server -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and in your Controller:

```
public class MyControllerName:Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyActionName(MyModel model)
    {
        // add code here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.